# Alter Rename function in SQL generates syntax error

Tags: sql, azure-data-studio

I am trying to change the name of one of the columns in my table using the rename function in SQL, but it always shows "**Incorrect Syntax near 'RENAME'**".

I've tried rewriting the specific part again and also used the Change function as well, which resulted in the same error.

SQL RENAME ERROR(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLiFI.png)

```
ALTER TABLE Employeesalary
RENAME COLUMN Gross_Pay TO Salary;
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME COLUMN ...` does **NOT** exist for SQL Server - check out the [official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) on how to do this for SQL Server